# Cases where transcendental numbers can add up to a rational number?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, summation, rational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Other than sums like $π + (1 - π)$, obviously. Can two transcendental numbers add up to a rational number? Or how about an infinite series of them?

Comment: All cases of two transcendental numbers adding up to a rational are of the form $x + (a - x) = a$ with $x$ transcendental and $a$ rational.

Comment: Your example is not a special case, it is the general case. If $x+y=q\in\mathbb{Q}$ then it trivially means that $y=q-x$.

Comment: Consider that $$\pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + \cdots - \cdots $$ Now, divide each term on the RHS by $~\pi.$

Comment: This is actually a good question. Besided the "trivial case" which you've pointed out and @Mark generalized it's often interesting to analyse the sum of two trancendtal numbers. Take for example $e+\pi$ - we don't know whether is algebraic or trancendal.

Comment: Take any conditionally convergent series of transcendental numbers, like $\Sigma (-1)^n \pi/n$. By the Riemann rearrangement theorem, the terms in the series can be rearranged to sum to any number, including rational ones.

Comment: @vitamind Interesting yes , but with too little context. Concerning $e+\pi$ and $e\cdot \pi$ : Although at least one of them must be transcendental , neither of those numbers is even known to be irrational.

Comment: Although not clarified , I would assume that the author means finite sums.